# "Reference to type Routevaluedictionary claims it is defined in system.web, but it could not be found" While using Ajaxextension command

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax

The error in the title occurred in ASP.NET MVC and C#

This is the error

[image: 1]

I want to use Ajax, but it does not work; Visual Studio does not recognize Ajax

Comment: Is your project's version is asp.net core 6?

Comment: Normally, if you confirm that you have added a reference to the System.Web.Routing assembly in the project, then it should be a problem with the .Net framework version. You need to change the version of .Net framework. Would it be convenient to share which version of the .Net framework you are using?

Comment: Yes bro i am using core 6.0, can you please share the suitable version to run that code

Comment: @AkashA Hello, you can switch to 5.0 first. If it doesn't work its read the comments below.

Comment: @AkashA Hello, I'm concerned that this error is caused by something else. Before that, I need to know whether your project has been migrated?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT no it was not migrated. I have tried in Framework 4.7, Intellisense was able to recognize Ajax. But in core 3.1, 5.0, 6.0 it shows the same error

Comment: @AkashA Hello, I went to check many documents. As the documentation<https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-ajax-ajaxextensions-actionlink(system-web-mvc-ajaxhelper-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-web-routing-routevaluedictionary-system-web-mvc-ajax-ajaxoptions)> says, only works with ASP.NET MVC 5.2.

Comment: @AkashA Hi, I posted that comment as an answer. If it is helpful to you, you can mark it so that more people can be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to check many documents. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-ajax-ajaxextensions-actionlink(system-web-mvc-ajaxhelper-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-web-routing-routevaluedictionary-system-web-mvc-ajax-ajaxoptions)) says, only works with ASP.NET MVC 5.2.